# Swift version of NSObject+AutoCoding

Tags: ios, swift

I use this auto coding lib a lot through my projects.

https://github.com/nicklockwood/AutoCoding

I think it is very useful. So I am wondering how I can implement the same extension in Swift?

Thanks.

Additional question:
Is it possible to write AnyObject into a file? Or it has to inherit from NSObject and conform NSCoding protocol?

Answer (score 2):

From looking at this project, the object does not have to conform to `NSCoding`. But only Objective-C properties are saved. So for a Swift object, it will only work with the properties that are visible to Objective-C (with `@objc` and/or `dynamic`, and the type of the property is one that can be bridged to an Objective-C type).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a little utility that simplifies NSCoding in Swift: https://github.com/mustafa/SwiftCoding

Comment: What are the advantages of using that instead of AutoCoding or Mantle?